# Multiple Select - Material UI No funciona correctamente cuando inicializo el data source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui

Tengo un Multiple Select, el cual contiene un MenuItem con un label y un checkbox. Cuando **no** inicializo el array objects el select funciona adecuadamente:

[image: This is the correct operation]

Pero necesito inicializarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    var zonas = [];
    zonas.push({
        ZonaID: '1',
        Nombre: 'Norte'
    });        
    setZonasGrupo(zonas);
```

Sucede que cuando lo inicializo, los items inicializados no se pueden deseleccionar

[image: it happens that I cannot deselect the initialized element]

Espero haberme explicado y cualquier aporte será de mucha ayuda

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta todas las veces que quieras usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. 
Estaría bien que leyeras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.